# Can a tabaxi rogue with the Criminal background start with 8 skill proficiencies?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, rogue, proficiency

Assuming:

> If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind (skill or tool) instead. (PBR, p. 36; PHB, p. 126)

A Tabaxi Rogue with the Criminal Background has the following skill proficiencies:

- **Racial (Tabaxi):** Stealth and Perception
- **Class (Rogue):** Four from Acrobatics, Athletics, Deception, Insight, Intimidation, Investigation, Perception, Performance, Persuasion, Sleight of Hand, and Stealth.
- **Background (Criminal):** Deception and Stealth.

With this in mind I'm looking at a build with the following proficiencies:

1. Stealth (racial)
2. Perception (racial)
3. Acrobatics (class)
4. Intimidation (class)
5. Persuasion (class)
6. Investigation (class)
7. Deception (background)
8. Sleight of Hand (background/Dex substitute for Stealth)

Is this valid by RAW?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes: those proficiency choices are supported by RAW

[From the Basic Rules,](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=38) and the same section in the PHB:

> **Proficiencies**
>
> If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different
>   sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind
>   (skill or tool) instead. (Basic Rules, p. 38)

Thus you can pick the other background skill proficiency to make up for an overlap/duplicate.  Your 8 skill proficiencies, as you presented, is supported by RAW.

#### Additional point on customization

[You can customize a background per the PHB/RAW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65840/must-my-background-be-chosen-from-the-given-options-in-the-players-handbook/65842?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C27.9422#65842)

**Customizing a Background**

> You might want to tweak some of the features of a background so it
>   better fits your character or the campaign setting. To customize a
>   background, you can replace one feature with any other one, choose any
>   two skills, and choose a total of two tool proficiencies or languages
>   from the sample backgrounds. You can either use the equipment package
>   from your background or spend coin on gear as described in chapter 5. (PHB p. 125).

I have found, from both sides of the table, that a collobrative workup of the background/back story between DM and player makes for a good fit between the player and the campaign.

Comment: Awesome. At first blush 8 proficiencies seemed high, but I'm stumbling on builds that have 18!

Comment: @Dre  Yeah, we have a Q&A that shows how high it can get.  [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87691/22566) shows how you can get 13 by level 4.  The big deal is Rogue, who starts with 4, and Bards who also get lots of skills proficiency add ons.  [And another](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120807/22566) max illustration.