# Custom homebrew Backgrounds? What are some good references?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, background

I was wondering. Where I would find some good places to find some custom backgrounds in D&D 5e for reference when making my own custom campaign and maybe even contribute to the list with my own custom backgrounds. I'm looking for Backgrounds that are like the ones listed in the PHB that have options and are fully fleshed out with traits, ideals, bonds and flaws. Ones that have a player participating would role and receive a random composite of features that create an interesting identity and role playing environment for players to stretch there acting legs in. Anyone know of one?

Comment: Can you add a tag for the game you're playing? There are many RPGs and if you don't tell us which one you're playing, we can't really help. Also check out our [help] to see how we work, and welcome to the site!

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close as "unclear" for the reasons Erik stated. SE just takes the average reason when there are multiple close votes for multiple reasons. As for whether _I_ think this is a shopping question or not, there are other _official_ backgrounds that one could use to judge their own homebrew against (I won't list those official backgrounds here, lest this comment become an answer; also I'd be assuming D&D 5e, and we don't know that, which is why I voted to closed) so this could at least be reworded to _not_ be a shopping question (I think) if the focus is on _official_ content.

Comment: @NathanS Agreed - but OP is specifically asking to not use the existing and where to find custom.

Comment: NathanS and Erik, Thank you for getting back to me so quick. I'm just wondering what you mean by shopping. The tour I read through made no mention to Shopping. Is the goal to keep people on the site to maximize ad revenue so linking people to other sources would be prohibited? This is my best guess to what one might mean by I'm shopping. Or is it that you think I'm just posting Questions to get rep enough to contribute to other peoples questions?

Comment: Can you explain why making a custom background as described in PHB pages 124-126 isn't an option?  [A related question is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65840/22566).  "Shopping" is an SE term that covers a broad variety of "where can I find this somewhere else" kinds of questions.  That is the class of questions your question seems to fall into.  [Here is a meta post discussion of what a "shopping" question is](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7413/22566)

Comment: Generally "recommend me places to find X" and similar are going to be labeled as shopping. [Here is one meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/how-can-i-ask-for-recommendations-without-getting-my-question-closed-as-shoppin), and if you search for "shopping" on the meta site you will get better definitinos. It's not saying that you are doing anything wrong, just that the question itself is not worded to be a great fit. You can also read [the help section](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about on topic subjects. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Brian "Shopping" in this context is short for "Workshopping", i.e. "the process of working out how a character should be built". It's not intended to mean "the process of purchasing and selling goods".

Comment: Here [is a post on "list" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/380710) which is what "shopping" questions are a sub set of.

Comment: @Xirema I don't think that's correct .... where did that usage come from?

Comment: According to the information provided, if I wanted to make this question a shopping one I would have had to ask "what is a good custom background for X character." To get back to the point of the question; is there a list of additional backgrounds for DnD 5e? For example, a pirate is listed in the PHB as a subset of sailor, but almost no oppositions for traits, ideals, bonds and flaws match a pirate. So for a person that likes improve and rolling dice to determine personality features as a DM. I would have no option for doing so going just from the PHB for a Pirate.

Comment: I'm not sure why the intent of my question is a consideration as to weather or not anyone helps answer it. I'm asking where is an example of a custom background that is more then just a list of proficients and stats, one with a personality, and I got back you're too vague and shoppy for me to answer. :/ Maybe I should just stick to scouring the internet.

Comment: @Brian if you ask this exact same question on reddit.com/r/dnd or someplace similar, I could provide you with an answer there.

Comment: If you get 20 rep, you can also hop into [chat]. That may be a good place to start with to help focus your question and see if we're the right place to ask it.